# Do you need lab courses for theoretical physics grad school?

Tags: soft-question, education

Sorry if this question isn't appropriate for this forum.

I'm a math and physics junior undergrad who wants to go into theoretical physics, in the direction of string theory or something like that. I'm going to have taken a bunch of grad classes in math and physics by the time I'm done. But, I really don't want to take the lab classes that are required for the physics major since there are a lot of other classes I want to take instead, and the lab classes at my school have a reputation of being time-intensive & uninteresting.

So, I'm strongly considering getting a minor in physics because of this. My question is whether it is advisable to do this, and if it would look too awkward to not have a physics major because of lab courses, even if I'll have good graduate coursework done. I'm also planning on talking to some of my professors about this, but I wanted to get some additional input from this forum.

Comment: While it doesn't answer your question I have to say that avoiding lab work (yes, even the tedious basic lab work) will leave you with a hole in your preparation that will hurt unless you going into one of those subfields marked by a dearth of actual contact with experiment. You might plan to make it up by taking a couple of advanced labs in grad school, but *those* courses are hard enough even when you know your way around the tedious basics.

Answer (score 1):

The only real answer here is to *form a list of programs you might want to get into* and *check the requirements*. You really don't want to shoot from the hip on things like this. If it's not a requirement, you don't have to do it. If your academic performance is otherwise great, I don't see a department turning down a great student for reasons that don't relate to actual requirements. Of course, if you are at all uncertain that you'll come out of your senior year with a great academic record, you should do the lab classes ...